# Apache ProxyPass Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, proxypass

I have some trouble with Apache and Tomcat server inside same machine.
I want redirect a virtual host, kb.domain to an tomcat app kb.

I have read some post on internet but I don't found a solution to my problem.

My configuration have one Apache server (`http://domain`) and in same machine an tomcat server (`http://domain:8080`); in my Apache I have mapped a VirtualHost that respond to `kb.domain`  like this:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName kb.domain

    <Location />
    ProxyPass http://192.168.200.3:8080/kb
    ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.200.3:8080/kb
    </Location>
    </VirtualHost>
```

When I call the kb.domain url from browser he add an extra / at the end and go into redirect loop.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proxpass directives should be:

```
ProxyPass / http://192.168.200.3:8080/kb/
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.200.3:8080/kb/
```

Comment: Same result. The browser add an extra / and say redirect loop message

Comment: @stefanopulze where does the browser add this extra slash and are you sure it's the browser doing this?

Comment: The first time i enter "kb.domain" in url bar and press Enter. The browser show me "kb.domain//".

Comment: @stefanopulze try adding an extra slash to the end of the proxy target: `http://192.168.200.3:8080/kb/`. It looks like it may be a mod_dir thing on the tomcat end.

Comment: OMG, I have added last / and now Work well 
Thanks men! :D

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName kb.domain

    ProxyPass /kb http://localhost:8080/kb
    ProxyPassReverse /kb http://localhost:8080/kb

</VirtualHost>
```

If you want to pass regardless of path ( aka not /kb )

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName kb.domain

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: With this configuration work well only if I add kb at the end: example kb.domain/kb

Comment: Will address in answer.